# How do I display today's date twice in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(now() :: DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

The above query displays only once.

I want to display the above date twice or more.

Comment: `SELECT TO_CHAR(now() :: DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_CHAR(now() :: DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the same date twice side to side, just query it twice:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(now()::DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), TO_CHAR(now()::DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

If you want to display multiple rows, you can use a set-generating function, such as `generate_series`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(now()::DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
FROM   GENERATE_SERIES(1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,perfect